# Render partial View in a View Via @Helper to call the partial

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

OK So I'm just messing around, as I discovered @helpers as placed in the App_Code Folder for MVC.
my Index.cshtml, yes Razor beautifully calls my helper "MasterPersonHelper.cshtml"

`@MasterPersonHelper.ReturnPersonList();`

However If I place the call to the helper method in a partial View, (just playing around to see what happens ) and yes that partial is in the shared folder.

Then attempt to call the partial to render the results of the helper from my index.cshtml    @Html.Partial("ListPerson");

instead of directly calling the helper  V.S. claims it cant find the partial but it assuredly lists the path it is located at. " And can't see it"

I believe it just cant call the helper from the partial since the helper is out in the app_Code Directory since its printing the correct path of the partial in its error.

I researched this & just figured I'd ask or inform whatever..
Thanks

Sorry I had pretty pictures but I'm a noob here so yea No Go

SUMMARY 
View calls helper = beautiful

View (In Views\Controllername Folder)  calls partial ( In Shared Folder )
containing call to helper (in App_Code directory) = FAIL !!!!

with misleading error.

Peace

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding a "using" to the top of your partial?  For example:

```
@using MvcApplication1.Controllers.Helpers
```

Comment: Sure Glad to try anything ( Sorry I was out Friday) but what would this using statement reference ??   The goal here is for the partial to correctly "SEE" the @helper which is in the App_Code directory. She has no real namespace to reference..

Comment: partial:  `@model MvcApplication1.Models.Person
           
<span class ="scoobieDont">
@MasterPersonHelper.ReturnPersonList();
</span>`

Comment: HELPER  Apparently I can't paste the helper in but in the view Im testing with I am testing these lines   `@*
<span class ="scoobieDont">
@MasterPersonHelper.ReturnPersonList();
</span>
*@
@Html.Partial("ListPerson");`